# Wayland combine monitors

Tags: 22.04, multiple-monitors, wayland

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 on a Lenovo laptop. I have a LG 5k monitor(the one build specially for apple) connected over Thunderbolt. After the the OS detects it works fine, but there is just a problem. The LG is detected as 2 monitors, and I want to combine the two monitors into a single screen(to get the 5k effect). With `xrandr` I've found that was possible, but I've saw it is not anymore because of Wayland.

Do you have any suggestions on how to combine the 2 monitors into a singe screen for Wayland?

Thanks